# Restarting Puma in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, puma

Why must I restart Puma twice in Ubuntu for it to work?

```
# uname -a
Linux myapp 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# pumactl -v
2.6.0

# pumactl -S /home/myapp/tmp/puma.state restart --config /home/myapp/config/puma.rb
Command restart sent success

[...that's not working, Puma is still running...]

# pumactl -S /home/myapp/tmp/puma.state restart --config /home/myapp/config/puma.rb
[9703] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[9703] * Version 2.6.0, codename: Pantsuit Party
[9703] * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
[9703] * Environment: production
[9703] * Process workers: 2
[9703] * Phased restart available
[9703] * Listening on unix:///home/myapp/tmp/puma.sock
[9703] * Daemonizing...

[...ok now it worked...]
```

Comment: here is an closed similar issue https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/436. The latest puma 2.9.0 should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't trust this pumactl script. Just use `kill -SIGUSR2 <pid>` as recommended in the puma documentation itself : https://github.com/puma/puma.

Comment: Yes. any idea how to use it with capistrano ?